# annotationView override drawRect, image with alpha

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

Hello i want to override drawrect in my custom annotationView, so when i write

```
[[_mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation] setNeedsDisplay];
```

my annotation view will be redrawn and i wouldn't have to remove the annotation and add it again.

here is my drawRect

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage* theImage = nil;
    if( _pinType == T_UNKNOWN ) theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgU.png"];
    else theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgK.png"];
    [theImage drawInRect:rect];
}
```

The problem is that my images are with alpha and the alpha part is black.

So maybe anyone knows the solution or some suggestions to this? 
I've read a lot of post about this, also using core graphics, but didn't find the solution..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want this view to be partially transparent and display things under it? If so, use `[self setOpaque:NO]`. An opaque view's `drawRect` is responsible for drawing every pixel in the rectangle with a fully opaque color.

Answer (score 1):

This function will be work correct for iOS 5.0. When you will use iOS version < 5.0, you'll got alpha part as black.

To try use another method for draw your images. I don't know for what you use this code. To try use:

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: theImage];
image.opaque = NO;
[self.view addSubview: image];
```

Comment: I have tested this on device with iOS 5, but it still doesn't work. Your proposed initWithImage gives the same results. Thanks for you offer though.

Comment: To try to set parameter opaque for UIImageView, image.opaque = YES/NO.

Comment: @Infoq hey thank you very much, this was it, but Rob Napier was first so i'm gonna mark his answer as right one. Thank for your help!